# Why is NULL + 0 = NULL, but SUM(NULL, 0) = 0?

Tags: mysql

This returns `NULL`:

```sql
SELECT NULL + 0 adding;
```

And this returns `0`:

```sql
WITH t AS (SELECT NULL c UNION ALL SELECT 0) SELECT SUM(t.c) summing FROM t;
```

Can anybody help me understand this design decision and explain how it applies more broadly to other aggregations, table-valued functions and beyond?

Comment: If you're encountering NULL, you'll often need to `COALESCE()` to default it to something else to have consistent results.

Comment: Is the title of the question wrong? The body implies SUM(NULL, 0)=0, but the title says SUM(NULL, 0)=NULL...

Comment: sum function ignores null values.  + within a select when encountering null will always return null.  it's just how it works.  The question is what are you expecting? as pointed out coalesce often can be used to handle the null issue with data.  See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/306043/why-does-selecting-sum-return-null-instead-of-0-when-there-are-no-matching-rec

Comment: Expecting consistency between addition and sum is not unreasonable.

Comment: `SUM(NULL, 0)` Sum does not have two parameters it takes a single expression, `NULL + 0` = `NULL` because unknown + known = unknown

Comment: And the crucial point is that SUM isn't the equivalent of applying `+` across all the members of the set over which it's aggregating... it's applying `+` to all _non-null_ members. This discrepancy between `+` and SUM can catch people off-guard.

Comment: There's a discussion of this apparent inconsistency in "SQL-99 Complete, Really" which is available online for free. Here's a link directly to the section about NULLs and set functions: https://crate.io/docs/sql-99/en/latest/chapters/33.html#set-functions-and-the-ignore-nulls-policy

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that SQL was designed by committee. There are bound to be parts that are imperfect. In fact, from a relational theory perspective, everything about NULLs in SQL is pretty broken. Nevertheless, they are useful.

Answer (score 3):

`NULL + 0` is `NULL` because the `NULL` is undefined and therefore adding it to another value will give an undefined result (=NULL).

`WITH t AS (SELECT NULL c UNION ALL SELECT 0) SELECT SUM(t.c) summing FROM t;`  will give 0 as the aggregate function SUM will skip the NULL values.